# remove native ActionBar highlight of select

Tags: android

i want to remove default highlight of item selection in Android ActionBar, im using AppCompat

[image: icon on right get select]

i try to set `android:selectableItemBackground` to transparent by seting color, or transparent shape or event drawable transparent png but no success

```
<style name="NActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
</style>
```

[EDIT]

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.

    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="NTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NButton</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/NEditText</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/NActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="NThemeNoActionBar" parent="NTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>

<style name="NButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/big_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="NSmallButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/small_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="NEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="NActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonBarButton" />

<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: post all the style.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `actionBarItemBackground` theme attribute will allow you to change the action item selector.

If you're using it with ActionBarSherlock or ActionBarCompat, be sure to provide an entry with and without the `android:` prefix.

In your style you can use below lines:

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: you can use the same for AppCompat.

Comment: work fine, before i paste it in wrong place, i have to be in app theme not in actionBar theme :)